# Validate UTF-8 MySQL before upgrade | SonarQube

Tags: mysql, sonarqube

SonarQube's install guide says that UTF-8 must be set when setting up MySQL. Is there a way I can check if my MySQL instance is compatible before attempting the upgrade?

I've done a few checks and we seem to have UTF8 setup for the client, connection, results, and system. At the database and server level we have swedish case insensitive. We do have UTF8_general_ci set for the collation_collection.

This instance will not be used in a multi language situation (only Us English). Do my settings align with what they should or do I need to spin up an entirely new instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the url using jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8 (see for example [here](https://gist.github.com/bendo01/3769226)). Read also the MySql [Character Set Configuration](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-configuration.html) documentation page. The settings are used by the SonarQube program, plugins and upgradescripts.

Comment: Does setting the characterEncoding=utf8 in the jdbc connection override the default MySQL configs? My default MySQL is using latin1, with a default collation of latin1_swedish_ci. Do these still need to be adjusted for the entire MySQL instance to UTF8?

Comment: From the documentation: You can specify character sets at the server, database, table, and column level. Character set issues affect also the communication between client programs and the MySQL server. If you want the client program to communicate with the server using a character set different from the default, you'll need to indicate which one. To be sure, you should use the client setting and use CHARACTER SET and COLLATE when creating the database. See [here](https://gist.github.com/davidhyk/d6c92615223b8d7beb53).